# div element with border and border radius are not working in MPDF

Tags: html, mpdf

```html
<div style="border:1px solid black">2. Lorem ipsum dolor sitamet</div>
```

Here is the output:

[image: Output Image]

I tried with different element like `<p>`, `<span>`, etc. but with same issue

Comment: Is the `<div>` placed in a table?

Comment: @Ferris. Yes it is.

Comment: It seems `border-radius` is not supported on table-related elements - [MPDF Supported CSS](https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html) - or even for elements placed in there. See also here: https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/609 - especially [this comment](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/609#issuecomment-357229017).

Comment: @Ferris. I removed the DIV from table and it works. Thank you